# Fazer um parâmetro alterar o valor da variável com apontador

Tags: javascript, funções, ponteiro, parâmetros

É possível trabalhar com ponteiros no JS, caso sim, como faço isso?

No exemplo abaixo o objetivo é fazer a variável `str` ficar com o valor: "funcionou :D"

```
var str = "teste";

function ponteiro(texto){
   texto = "funcionou :D"
}

ponteiro(str);
```

Comment: so tem que dizer que `str = "funcionou :D"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagino que esteja falando de ponteiro ou referência, ou seja, você quer poder alterar a variável dentro da função e o valor se refletir na variável original usada como argumento da função. Isto não é possível diretamente em JS e em geral não faz sentido algo assim porque você pode retornar esse valor na função e aí mudar o valor na função chamadora:

```js
function apontador(texto) {
   return "funcionou :D";
}
var str = "teste";
str = apontador(str);
console.log(str);
```

Se você tem que retornar mais de um coisa e por isso está querendo fazer algo do tipo então o ideal seria retornar mais de um dado encapsulando em um objeto:

```js
function apontador(texto) {
   return ["funcionou :D", "Outro texto " + texto];
}
var str = "teste";
var objeto = apontador(str);
console.log(objeto[0]);
```

Você poderia usar um nome no *array* em vez de usar o índice numérico se achar que é importante.

Se ainda quiser muito insistir nisso tem como encapsular a variável em um objeto que seja por referência e aí obter o resultado que deseja:

```js
function apontador(objeto) {
   objeto[0] = "funcionou :D";
}
var str = "teste";
var objeto = [str];
apontador(objeto);
console.log(objeto[0]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/ReferenceParameter.js).

Novamente, desnecessário.

Tecnicamente uma *string* é uma referência, mas tem semântica de valor então ela não faz o que espera de forma automática, precisa de uma estrutura auxiliar por JavaScript não ter uma sintaxe que dê a semântica de referência de forma natural.

Comment: Obrigado Maniero pela resposta! Estou procurando entender melhor o funcionamento dos ponteiros para poder aplicar em outra função que estou criando, nesta outra faz mais sentido usar ponteiros sim :D

Comment: JS não tem ponteiros aparentes então você não tem como aprender usar ponteiro em JS.